# Is it possible to embed functions as LISP list elements?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Consider the example of creating a date library. We may have a list that maps the month index to the number of days in the month:

```
(defparameter *daymap*
  '(0 31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31))
```

Suppose we also have a global variable tracking a year:

`(defvar *year* 1900)`

Is there a way to define the `*daymap*` list so that `(nth 2 *daymap*)` evaluates to 29 on a leap year?

I've attempted the following (and similar) like this to no success:

```
(defparameter *daymap*
  '(0 31 #'(if (= 0 (mod *year* 4)) 28 29)
    31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31))
```

Entering `(nth 2 *daymap*)` in the REPL evaluates to: `#'(if (= 0 (mod *year* 4))` instead of `28` or `29`.

Comment: A vector makes more sense than a list for that, btw

Comment: note that the leap rule is slightly more complex: "This extra leap day occurs in each year that is an integer multiple of 4 (except for years evenly divisible by 100, but not by 400)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to embed functions as list elements: functions are first-class and lists can contain elements of any type.  However `nth` just gets the nth element of some list.  If that element is a function then the value is a function: it won't magically call it for you.

Your example is however confused.  `#'x` is read as `(function x)`, so `'(1 2 #'(if ...) ...)` reads as `'(1 2 (function (if ...)))`.  A form like `(function ...)` will *evaluate* to a function, but in your example it's in a quoted form – a literal – and is therefore not evaluated at all.  So is no function in this bit of data, but rather just a list beginning `function`.

You also have [the syntax of the `function` special operator](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_fn.htm) wrong: it is `(function <name>)` where `<name>` is either the name of a function or a lambda expression.

If you want to embed a function into the list you need to both get the syntax of `function` forms correct, and not have the list be literal data, so that the form is evaluated.  For instance

```
(defparameter *daymap*
  `(0 
    31 
    ,#'(lambda () (if (= 0 (mod *year* 4)) 28 29))
    31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31))
```

(This is more concisely written as

```
(defparameter *daymap*
  `(0 
    31 
    ,(lambda () (if (= 0 (mod *year* 4)) 28 29))
    31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31))
```

since `lambda` is macro whose expansion is `(function (lambda () ...))`.)

And now you can easily write a little shim around `nth` to do what you want:

```
(defun nth/call (n list)
  (let ((it (nth n list)))
    (if (functionp it)
        (funcall it)
      it)))
```

Or even

```
(defun nth/force (n list)
  ;; MUNGE
  (do ((it (nth n list)
           (if (functionp it) (funcall it) it)))
      ((not (functionp it)) it)))
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is a version that correctly computes the number of days in a month for a particular year on the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year):

```
(defparameter *daymap* '(0 31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31))

(defparameter *year* 1900)

(defun nbdays (month)
  (case month
    (2 (if (zerop (mod *year* 4))
           (if (zerop (mod *year* 100))
               (if (zerop (mod *year* 400))
                   29
                   28)
               29)
           28))
    (t (nth month *daymap*))))
```